# A* Search in Python Priority Queue

Tags: python, search, graph

I am trying to write an A* search to solve a maze in Python, however I am struggling to find a built in priority queue that works for this. I am using PriorityQueue at the moment, but it offers no functionality in order to change an items priority, which is a problem in the commented section at the bottom of the algorithm (in the else if statement).

Does anyone have any idea what I could do in that else if block, or what built in priority queue would give me this functionality?

```
def A_search(maze, start, end):
expanded = 0 # use to track number of nodes expanded by the algorithm
node1 = Node(start,0)
frontier = PriorityQueue()
frontier.put((dist_to_goal(node1,end) + node1.get_cost(), node1))
visited = []
in_frontier = [] # keep track of items in frontier, PriorityQueue has no way to peek
in_frontier.append(node1)
while(True):
    if(frontier == []):
        return(None,expanded)
    curr = (frontier.get())[1]
    in_frontier.remove(curr)
    expanded += 1
    if(curr.get_loc() == end):
        return(curr,expanded)
    visited.append(curr.get_loc())
    neighbors = find_neighbors(maze, curr.get_loc())
    for neighbor in neighbors:
        node_n = Node(neighbor,node1.get_cost()+1)
        node_n.parent = curr
        if(neighbor not in visited) and (node_n not in in_frontier):
            frontier.put((dist_to_goal(node_n,end) + node1.get_cost(), node_n))
            in_frontier.append(node_n)
        # else if node_n is in frontier w/ a higher path cost then replace it w/ current
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest you will find in the built-in libraries is [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html).

After changing the priority you need to call either `heapq.heapify` (costs O(n) time but will not change A* overall complexity) or use the internal `heapq._siftdown` function at O(log n) time.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the item priority, is discussed in the official python documentation about the `heapq` module in the priority queue implementation notes: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes
Using these notes, I managed to write my own `PriorityQueue` Implementation that supports adding a task and updating it's priority if it exists. It consists in using an `entry_finder` `dict` which point to tasks in the priority queue. Updating a task's priority, simply consists in marking the existing task as deleted and inserting it with the new priority.
In this implementation, you can use method `add_task`

```py
class PriorityQueue():
    REMOVED = '<removed-task>'
    def __init__(self):
        self.pq = []
        self.entry_finder = {}
        self.counter = itertools.count()


    def add_task(self, task, priority=0):
        if task in self.entry_finder:
            self.remove_task(task)
        count = next(self.counter)
        entry = [priority, count, task]
        self.entry_finder[task] = entry
        heappush(self.pq, entry)

    def remove_task(self, task):
        entry = self.entry_finder.pop(task)
        entry[-1] = self.REMOVED

    def pop_task(self):
        while self.pq:
            priority, count, task = heappop(self.pq)
            if task is not self.REMOVED:
                del self.entry_finder[task]
                return task
        return None
```